# Asking the employer to not employing someone you are not comfortable to work with

Tags: employer-relations, employees, employer, employment

So, here is my problem.

Right now I am a third year student at the bachelor program. I landed a job of my dream and it turned out so that the employer in the case is my lecturer, he is very young, just 4-5 years older than me. I really in deep love with the job and I really need money. I am living in the dormitory with two other guys who are just interested in the same things as I do, but have different attitudes and values. They do not know that I got a job and if they will get to know it, then they inevitably ask the lecturer to employ them as well and I do not want to work with them, it will be very uncomfortable for me and I will stop getting pleasure from the job and will hate every minute of it. So I am thinking about asking the employer not to employ them in the case they ask about it. I understand that it may be very selfish, but in my case it will be impossible to find a better job than that one.

So, is it acceptable for me to ask my new employer **not** to employ these people? What the employer may respond in the case? How can I tell that to the employer? Should I ask it to be a private matter, so that no one else know about the conversation? How can I start the conversation if I am very shy about the problem to be discussed?

If it is not an appropriate place to ask such thing, then, please, tell me where I can ask it.

Comment: If you should or not ask is really up to you, we can't tell you what to do on that. Would you consider rephrasing your post to something that is more on-topic?

Comment: "What should I do" isn't something we can help; "Is this a good idea?" or "How might my employer respond?" on the other hand are questions we can answer.

Comment: @pasteMyCode - I've done a minor edit to your question, hopefully it doesn't substantially change your intent but if so feel free to edit yourself or to rollback my edit.

Comment: Why worry about until there is a job opening? Companies don't just hire willy nilly anybody who asks.

Comment: @Erik, I updated the question.

Comment: I'm going to go against the grain here and say if you are honest with your boss, I don't see a problem with it ONLY if you know they are going to get hired and you know you will be leaving if they do get hired.

Comment: @Mike, it sounds good, but still I am very afraid to create even more problems by asking such a thing.

Comment: Is it possible to just not tell them about the job?

Comment: @pasteMyCode if you are going to leave for sure, and you are sure they are going to get hired, I'd mention it. Otherwise, I wouldn't make a problem that's not there.

Comment: @AffableAmbler, not exactly. I am going to stay there (at the job office) for the whole night sometimes and I will have to say where I was at night. Actually I am thinking about saying that I got  a job but not specifying which job I got exactly.

Comment: On what are your objections based?  Doubts about their technical or professional abilities, or just that you don't like them personally?

Comment: If you stopped living with them, would that make a difference? You may find some people are more tolerable in smaller doses.

Comment: Not sure its a good idea to initiate conflict at a workplace.
Especially when its your dream-job, as soon as you raise this issue - it will stop being your dream-job.
It comes up to your decision what is more important, current dorm placement or work.
If you sure you would not be able to keep it to yourself where you work, you can move :)

Comment: @Jonathon Cowley-Thom, I suppose both. I do not like them and they have bad skills.

Comment: @JeffO, it is exactly the reason. I can not stop living with them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really don't think you can ask in your situation. If you'd been working for this employer for a long time and were able to point to specific issues why they wouldn't be suitable for the role (and that has to be more than just I don't get on with them, it would actually have to be something that would materially affect their capability to do the job they were being hired for) then *maybe*, but it doesn't sound like that's your situation here.

If you really feel that you need to then first of all you'd be best off waiting until it is actually on the table - not just a vague possibility. By this I mean wait until such a time as they have an actual interview - at that point you can talk to your employer and suggest some reasons why you think it would be a bad idea to hire them - and as I said before this **has** to be centered around reasons why you think they wouldn't be suitable for the job. If the issues are purely personal then, with rare exceptions, it's just going to come across as petty and childish.

The sad fact is that working with people who you don't get on with personally, even people that you loathe is a fact of life, it's not great and it won't be the case in every job that you have but it **is** going to happen to you at some point in your career, I can practically guarantee it - and being able to do so is a key component of being professional. So I'm not trying to be harsh here but I think you need to adjust your thinking a bit and focus on how you would remain professional if this were to happen and in the meantime I wouldn't exactly be advertising this job of yours around them because that may well be sufficient to prevent it ever becoming an issue in this case.

Comment: How can I tell that to the employer?

Comment: If you re-read the answers he said that this is nothing you can ask or tell your employer. You need to adjust your way of thinking when it comes to these types of scenarios. I've been working with people who I strongly disagreed with, but still had to make it work, FOR MY WORK. If you don't want them to become employed there, you either don't discuss your work around them or tell them that you don't want them at your work place (It sounds harsh yes, but if that is what you want you need to be able to talk about it)

Answer (score 7):

> So, is it acceptable for me to ask my new employer not to employ these people?

**Absolutely not and this can fireback on you if you attempted.**

You are hired for doing a particular job which I assume does not include making hiring decisions. (Worse yet, influencing hiring based on your personal attitude conflicts)

Just focus on your job. You will have to work with all kinds of people throughout your career. You will never know about them before you (or they) join and you just have to deal with it. Why do you want to make it different now just because you know them already?

Comment: 'influencing hiring based on your personal attitude conflicts' exactly. I would like to add that you will have to work with people you won't like *everywhere*. There's always going to be the person you dislike, the person who annoys you, the bad apple. They are everywhere. It's up to you as a *professional* to learn how to deal with this and still do your job the best you can.

Comment: But by taking my chances I may will be able to eliminate the problem totally...